# Change the position of an existing item in a MFC CTreeCtrl

Tags: tree, mfc

At the moment I am experimenting with the `CTreeCtrl` component of C++ MFC. I would like to move an existing item to another position in the tree by using a new parent for the item. It would be important that the child items are moved too.

I think that you can use `InsertItem` with `TVINSERTSTRUCT` to achieve the goal. But I don't know exactly how.

It would be nice if you could provide a code snippet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Delete the old one and insert it again - use the `hInsertAfter` member.

Comment: The Problem is to insert the item again. There is much stuff attached to it, for example attributes like images or user-specific data. I simply can't reproduce all of this in order to call InsertItem

Comment: Why would you? Get the item, change the stated property. Set the item.

Comment: This sounds quite strange imo. How were they inserted in the first place? Can't you just run the same code (limited to the item in question and its children)? Don't you still have the data you put there available? That is, is the tree-control the only data-structure that holds your data? Still, it is possible to write a recursive function (trees are hierarchical) retrieving the items' data (`TVM_GETITEM`/`TreeView_GetItem()`) with the `mask` member requesting all fields (or only the ones you know you inserted) and insert them again, then delete the original. Not the best solution though...

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, how to do this? The `hParent` and `hInsertAfter` are members of the `TVINSERTSTRUCT` structure (not of the `TVITEM` one), which can only used with an insert operation. There is no way to change an item's parent in any other way (or at least I can't find one).

Comment: Alright, so why can't he get the item, change the parent. Delete current item in tree, add the new structure again? He has it as a structure so why can't he insert it again with the new parent?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, the OP said he wants to move the item's children as well, and the `TVITEM` structure contains information about a single item only. The children have to be inserted again, one by one unfortunately (unless the children callback mechanism is used, which I think he doesn't use).

Comment: Oh. I assumed it you changed one that children would logically follow. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to your question on [CodeGuru](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?324597-Move-up-down-CTreeCtrl-item) (from year 2005).

In case the link won't survive much longer, here is the relevant code:

```cpp
void CMyTreeCtrl::MoveItem(HTREEITEM hitemToBeMoved, HTREEITEM hitemInsertAfter)
{
    TV_INSERTSTRUCT tvStruct;
    TCHAR cBuffer[50];
    HTREEITEM hNewItem;

    tvStruct.item.hItem = hitemToBeMoved;
    tvStruct.item.cchTextMax = 49;
    tvStruct.item.pszText = cBuffer;
    tvStruct.item.mask = TVIF_CHILDREN | TVIF_HANDLE | TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE | TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;
    GetItem(&tvStruct.item);
    tvStruct.hParent = GetParentItem(hitemInsertAfter);
    tvStruct.hInsertAfter = hitemInsertAfter;
    tvStruct.item.mask = TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE | TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;

    hNewItem = InsertItem(&tvStruct);
    HTREEITEM hChild = GetChildItem(hitemToBeMoved);
    while(hChild != NULL)
    {
        TransferItem(hChild, hNewItem);
        DeleteItem(hChild);
        hChild = GetChildItem(hitemToBeMoved);
    }
    DeleteItem(hitemToBeMoved);
}
```

Here is the referenced function `TransferItem`:

```
BOOL CMyTreeCtrl::TransferItem(HTREEITEM hitemDrag, HTREEITEM hitemDrop) //Used to transfer items to a new parent.
{
    TV_INSERTSTRUCT     tvstruct;
    TCHAR               sztBuffer[50];
    HTREEITEM           hNewItem, hFirstChild;

        // avoid an infinite recursion situation
    tvstruct.item.hItem = hitemDrag;
    tvstruct.item.cchTextMax = 49;
    tvstruct.item.pszText = sztBuffer;
    tvstruct.item.mask = TVIF_CHILDREN | TVIF_HANDLE | TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE | TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;
    GetItem(&tvstruct.item);  // get information of the dragged element
    tvstruct.hParent = hitemDrop;
    tvstruct.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
    tvstruct.item.mask = TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE | TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;
    hNewItem = InsertItem(&tvstruct);

    while ((hFirstChild = GetChildItem(hitemDrag)) != NULL)
    {
        TransferItem(hFirstChild, hNewItem);  // recursively transfer all the items
        DeleteItem(hFirstChild);        // delete the first child and all its children
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Please don't throw a blob of code at the readers. Explain the basic idea behind the method.

Comment: What is `TransferItem()`?

Comment: OK, nice to have some code snippet to demonstrate the operations on tree-view control items; it can really help. One notice though, this code makes two assumptions: a) the item can only be moved to a new position but under the same parent and b) the item may have children at up to 1 level of depth, ie "leaves". If something more that these is needed, it must be modified accordingly: recursion (to work deeper than the 1st-level children) and the function should also be taking the (destination) parent as a parameter, not just the new position (`hitemInsertAfter`).